# ng2 component not loading as expected

Tags: angular, typescript

I've wired up an app with ng2. My ng2 wireup contains a basic Users component which is used as a template for additional components. I've added a new component ComponentX to my ng2 wireup and it follows the same implmentation pattern as the Users component.

I've included ComponentX on the same page as my Users component but ComponentX isn't loading on the page although the Users component is. The CDT Console doesn't show any errors. The CDT Sources pane show the users.service.ts file but doesn't show the componentx.service.ts or componentx.component.ts files.

The app.module.ts file loaded by CDT does show the updates for ComponentX. Any idea what the problem might be or how to go about debugging this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. To get help with your problem, consider rewriting your question to focus on describing in detail the error you're experiencing, and what you've done to debug it. Pay particular attention to what you've done. Hint: add console log statements to constructors, on-initialization, and on-destroy to see what phase your component is failing in.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the Angular-CLI? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

It provides a much easier way to build and hook up the components of your application, compile them and deploy them.

Comment: +1 -- please take this advice OP. The Angular CLI addresses many of the common, simple errors developers face with Angular.